# How is DateDiff implemented in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the following code in my statement.

```
datediff(minute, visit.nexttime, visit.endtime)
```

the results vary.

I will show a couple of results.

- 0:24:26  -       25
- 0:32:14  -       32
- 0:05:12  -       5
- 0:06:28  -       7
- 0:03:52  -       4
- 0:03:32  -       3

The first one, 24 rounds up to 25 while there is only 26 seconds.

The second one, 32 remains where the second is 14.

The third one, 5 remains 5, fair enough.

The fourth one, 6 rounds up to 7 while there are only 28 seconds.

The fifth one, 3 round up to 4 because of 52 seconds.

The last one, 3 remains 3 even there are 32 seconds.

Why is that?

I use the following code to get my first column.

```
CONVERT(varchar(6), datediff(second, visit.nexttime, visit.endtime)/3600)
+ ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (datediff(second, visit.nexttime, visit.endtime) % 3600) / 60), 2)
+ ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), datediff(second, visit.nexttime, visit.endtime) % 60), 2) 
as 'Transaction Time'
```

Comment: Consider changing the title of your question to 'how is DateDiff implemented in MySQL'.  Currently it appears like you are asking how to use DateDiff, which is why your first answer is not useful.

Comment: Your question is tagged mysql, but are your sure mean mysql? MySqls datediff takes 2 parameters as far as I can tell...

Comment: the names r always confusing.. microsoft sql server is mysql or mssql??

Comment: You are pulling the difference between 2 fields, what is the value of the first field?
From a minute point of view there is only a 2 minute difference between 10:00:32 and 10:02:32.
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @william: Microsoft Sql Server is MSSql or just sql-server. MySql is a completely different engine with a completely different function set.

Comment: the first column is the results for my calculation in second and change back to HH:mm:ss. the second one is the same function in minute.

Comment: What I mean is, what is the value in the visit.nexttime and visit.endtime, and what are you trying to show with the minute field? the duration of the visit?

Comment: yea.. the value by misusing endtime and nexttime.. like 
nexttime is 08:00:00 and endtime is 08:15:00.. first column is 00:15:00 and second column is 15..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) explains why you are getting those results.

The return value is described as this:

> Returns the count (signed integer) of
> the specified datepart boundaries
> crossed between the specified
> startdate and enddate.

Since you specified `minute` for the `datepart`, I would expect this means the seconds are ignored and it just counts how many times the minute changes between the `startdate` and `enddate`.

eg.

If the `startdate` and `enddate` were 50 seconds apart in the same minute, it would return 0.

If the `startdate` and `enddate` were only 5 seconds apart but in different minutes, it would return 1.

Comment: A surprising side effect of the boundary counting occurs with the old `DATETIME` data type with a 1/300 second accuracy. The actual fractional millisecond values are used instead of the rounded millisecond values shown in most displays. `DATEDIFF(ms, '0.000', '0.003') = 3`, `DATEDIFF(ms, '0.003', '0.007') = 3`, and `DATEDIFF(ms, '0.007', '0.010') = 4`. Makes sense if you think of the values as `0.0000000`, `0.0033333`, `0.0066666`, and `0.0100000`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z2NN16n6).

Answer (score 1):

`Datediff` is a bit strange and rather nonintuitive. And it works this way since old Sybase days.

In your case `datediff(m, x, y)` completely ignores the seconds.

You have the same problem when you try to calculate ages:

```
select datediff (y, '2010-12-31', '2011-01-01')
```

This doesn't mean that the rounded difference is about 1 year, it only says that 1 new year happened.

To get the results you intend, you must take the difference at a more granular base, as you did using seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to the MySql documentation. It should clarify this for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: that one only explains the date part. the trouble i m having is time part, minutes to be precise.

Comment: This link doesn't provide any help for the OP - he already knows how to use the function, and is asking about the implementation.

Comment: It is a pet peeve of mine to just link to another website without providing any info.  There is no guarantee that the website will exist in the future - I think you should at least summarize what you found there, and use the link as a reference only.  Unfortunately this link didn't answer the question anyway...

Comment: @Kirk Broadhurst your absolutely right... it's like stealing brownie points instead of earning them. I will make sure to improve my future contributions.

Comment: How is an answer describing a MySQL function even relevant for a question about a SQL Server function?